# fuseki doesn't select from dbpedia on my computer

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, fuseki

I have fuseki running on my computer. version 1.1.1. but it when I enter a query to select from dbpedia it doesnt return anything. The query made is suppose to return http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Guitarist110151760 as ?artistKind and http://semanticweb.org/laura/ontologies/2014/9/untitled-ontology-26#Guitar as ?instrument.
I made the ontology in protege and used a restriction that Guitarist110151760 playsInstrument Guitar.

```
PREFIX instru: <http://www.semanticweb.org/laura/ontologies/2014/9/untitled-ontology-26#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

select ?artistKind ?instrument
FROM <http://www.semanticweb.org/laura/ontologies/2014/9/untitled-ontology-26#>

WHERE
{
  ?artistKind instru:playsInstrument ?instrument.
  SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> { 
    dbpedia:Eric_Clapton rdf:type ?artistKind . } 
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where do you enter a query? What does your query look like? Have you loaded the data from DBpedia into your local Fuseki installation?

Comment: What is your query?  Do you mean that you're using something like `service <http://dbpedia.org/sparql/> { ... }`?  That should work, I'd think.  If you're doing something like `select ... from <...> where { ... }`, then no, it probably wouldn't.  But without seeing your query, we can't diagnose your problem.

Comment: I edited the question and added the query to the post

Comment: I loaded my ontology in fuseki..

Answer (score 0):

Use website http://dbpedia.org/sparql to perform successful queries on dbpedia ontology because jena fusiki is used to perform queries on **local** ontologies inside hard disk (by loading owl files)